# Statistical comparison of 3 relative survival values

Tags: p-value, survival, z-test

I have to compare relative survival (have 5-year estimates with SEs and patients number per group) across 3 time periods. Cannot use log-rank etc as (probably) it is impossible to operate with raw data for this job. Found this (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6671129) but the mathematical prerequisites were too much). I feel that I should use Z-scores or a Poisson model; however I did not find a simple algorithm (suitable for a medical professional) to do this. What are my options?

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286627/how-do-i-compare-2-survival-curves

Comment: unfortunately I do not see any connection with my case